How to authenticate (OIDC SSO) between applications
I have two OIDC server applications created in .net core c# which have their own server and client, After successful login from server app 1, I need to provide a razor page with the button "Navigate to server app 2" ( Still this process is working fine )
Now clicking the above button should redirect and auto login server app 2 with the authorization code provided by server app 1, In both applications I have used openiddict.
Below is the sequence for the expected flow ,

How to redirect to server app 2 with auth code from app1 and reissue a new token in server app 2 to access the resources in app2 , can someone please guide

To enable Server 2 to validate tokens issued by Server 1 when using JWT:

Share the Public Key or Secret: Ensure Server 2 has access to the public key (for asymmetric encryption) or the shared secret (for symmetric encryption) that Server 1 uses to sign its tokens.

Implement Token Validation Logic: Configure Server 2 to validate the tokens issued by Server 1. This involves verifying the token's signature, issuer, audience, and other relevant claims.


Once Server 2 validates the token issued by Server 1, it can then issue its own token for future communications with Server 2.
